# Lucene: Topdocs index search return zero

Tags: java, lucene

```
Query q = parser.parse(query);
            //Checked;System.out.println(q);
            TopDocs hits = searcher.search(q,numResultsToReturn);
            int test = hits.totalHits;
            System.out.println(test);
```

The test give result = zero. What may cause this?

1. I believe I set up correct path for indexsearcher.
2. I think I already create the correct index files.

Comment: result=0 means it has not found any hits. We cant really tell you more like this obvious answer. You might search for terms not in the index or your index might be empty. who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Problem sloved. I use Stringfield instead of "textfield" to be searched.
Should textfield. It is designed for key wordsearch.